# NextJS: How to display static, outsourced content (made on Wordpress), in the app?

Tags: wordpress, next.js, static-pages

I'm creating an application and we need a landing/marketing page that someone else is creating on WordPress. I see a lot on NextJs with Headless WordPress but that uses the WordPress backend and I need to display pages created on WordPress. Is an iframe my only option or is there a better way? I'm not particularly familiar with how WordPress works so my question could be missing something.